# How to solve a quadratic Diophantine equation without trial and error by just inputting integer values for one of the variables?

Tags: quadratics, diophantine-equations, integers

I’m looking for a way to find only integer solution pairs to a dual-variable quadratic equation without trial and error.

For example: $$(a+3\sqrt 5)^2+a-b\sqrt 5=51$$

Valid solution pairs are any points on the graph of $(a+3\sqrt 5))^2+a-b\sqrt 5=51$, but the only integer pairs are $(2,12)$ and $(-3,-18)$
Since the above equation is solvable by rearrangement and then comparison(b=6a,a²+a=6), it was suggested that I change my example:
a^2+ab^2+2b^2-ab=50
How would one find only integer solutions for this equation(a,b) without trial and error?

Comment: Note that the left hand expands to $a^2+ 6a\sqrt 5 + a - b \sqrt 5 +45$ from which we deduce that $b=6a$ and $a^2+a=6$.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that but I was only using that equation as an example, I wanted a general method, this is quite a rare case(I got it from an old exam paper)

Comment: Substituting one variable is no general method, I think. Consider $x^2-2y^2=1$.

Comment: There are a lot of Diophantine equations out there.  If the one you asked about was not the one you had in mind, please edit your question accordingly.  Perhaps you were thinking more along the lines of [Pell's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) but it's hard to guess from what you wrote.